# Display file contents in a TextArea

Tags: java

Ok so I will try to make this as understandable as possible.

I have created a simple GUI with an "open" button and a textArea (along with other stuff but that's not important right now). Basically I am creating a method that when I click the Open button it displays the contents of the file in the textArea.

I believe 99% of the method I have written is correct but I keep getting a NullPointerException and I don't quite understand why. Hopefully my code will clear up any confusion on what I am asking, I will comment on the line of code where I get the exception. Here is my code:

**Application class (Basic setup of my GUI):**

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;

public class Application extends JFrame {

public OutputPanel outPanel = new OutputPanel();
public BarcodePanel barPanel = new BarcodePanel();
public ButtonPanel btnPanel = new ButtonPanel();
public ReferencePanel refPanel = new ReferencePanel();

public Application() {
super("Book Processor");
this.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

btnPanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT));
outPanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT));
refPanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT));

add(btnPanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
add(outPanel, BorderLayout.WEST);
add(refPanel,BorderLayout.SOUTH);
}//end constructor

public static void main(String[] args) {
Application frame = new Application();
frame.setSize(1000,500);
frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
frame.setVisible(true);
}//end main

}//end class
```

The next set of code is my ButtonPanel class(this is where I am having an issue) So I have an `openFile method`, that when I click the button it should display the contents of the file in the textArea. Again I receive a NullPointerException and I do not understand why. Here is the code for this class:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.Closeable;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectInput;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.Scanner;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFileChooser;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class ButtonPanel extends JPanel{


JButton btnOpen = new JButton("Open");
OutputPanel outPanel = new OutputPanel();
Scanner input;

public ButtonPanel() {
ButtonHandler handler = new ButtonHandler();

add(btnOpen);
btnOpen.addActionListener(handler);

}//end constructor


 /**
  * Method for displaying the file onto the textArea.
  * 
  */
private void openFile() {
JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
chooser.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.FILES_ONLY);


int result = chooser.showOpenDialog(this);

String fileName;

fileName = chooser.getSelectedFile().getAbsolutePath();

try {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(Paths.get(fileName));
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    while(input.hasNextLine()) {

        sb.append(input.nextLine()+ "\n");

    }

    outPanel.txtOutput.setText(sb.toString());//my issue is with this line right here

} catch (IOException e) {

    e.printStackTrace();
}
finally {
    input.close();
}

}//end readFile



private class ButtonHandler implements ActionListener{

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

    if(e.getSource()== btnOpen) {

        openFile();

    }

}//end actionPerformed


}//end actionlistener


}//end class
```

Here is my last class, `OutputPanel`, this class contains the JTextArea:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;

import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;

public class OutputPanel extends JPanel{

public JTextArea txtOutput = new JTextArea(20,50);

public OutputPanel() {

add(txtOutput);

}//end constructor

}//end class
```

How do I get the textArea to display the contents of the file? More importantly, why am I getting this exception and what can I do to fix it? Hopefully this makes as much sense as possible, and I really appreciate any and all input from you guys.

Comment: `JTextArea` can actually read files itself - see [`JTextArea#read`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/text/JTextComponent.html#read-java.io.Reader-java.lang.Object-) for more details

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `NullPointerException` is actually been caused by

```
} finally {
    input.close();
}
```

Because `input` is `null` (well, obviously). This is because you're shadowing the variable in the `try-catch` block

```
try {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(Paths.get(fileName));
    //...
} finally {
    // This is null because the instance field has not been initialised
    input.close();
}
```

A better solution would be to make use of the [`try-with-resources` statement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html)

```
try (Scanner input = new Scanner(Paths.get(fileName))) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    while (input.hasNextLine()) {

        sb.append(input.nextLine() + "\n");

    }

    outPanel.txtOutput.setText(sb.toString());//my issue is with this line right here

} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

An even better solution would be to make use of `JTextArea`'s ability to read the contents of a `Reader`, for example...

```
try (FileReader reader = new FileReader(chooser.getSelectedFile())) {
    outPanel.txtOutput.read(reader, fileName);
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Now, before you ask why there's no content in your text area, the reason is because you create a new instance of `OutputPanel` in your `ButtonPanel` class, this has no relationship to the instance you created in your `Application` and added to the screen.

You will need to pass an instance of the `OutputPanel` to the `ButtonPanel` (via the constructor) so the references match up.

Personally, a better solution would be define an `interface` which had a `read` method which took a `File`.  `OutputPanel` would implement this `interface` and `ButtonPanel` would require a reference to an instance of this `interface`.  This decouples the code and prevents `ButtonPanel` from making unnecessary changes to the `OutputPanel` - because it's really not it's responsibility to do so - it's the `OutputPanel`s responsibility to load the file and display it

Comment: Holy cow! thank you so much! this has really helped!